# visual studio Reshaper and R-Tools have the same menu hotkey binding

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In visual studio, after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> both Rs for Resharper menu andf R Tools are underlined.

pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> activates neither of the menu items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio **Customize** dialog, **Commands** tab, **Menu bar**, you can select Resharper and **Modify Selection** to change & hotkey binding.